# JavaFX How to make a GridPane fit to ScrollPane parent?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, scrollpane, gridpane

I need page with a grid where entering some data so, using SceneBuilder ,  I put a GridPane inside an AnchorPane. The gridpane I need has huge height so I wrap it inside a ScrollPane and make the ScrollPane fitting to AnchorPane.
But now  when I expand the window gridpane doesn't resize like it doesn't fit the ScrollPane.
How Can I make gridpane resizing when I resize the window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `fitToWidth` property of the `ScrollPane` to `true` and make sure both the anchors of the `ScrollPane` are set.
You may also need to use appropriate constraints on the `GridPane` columns to resize the children of the `GridPane`.

#### Example

```xml
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <ScrollPane fitToWidth="true"
                    AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10"
                    AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10"
                    AnchorPane.topAnchor="10"
                    AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10">
            <content>
                <GridPane hgap="10">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets topRightBottomLeft="10"/>
                    </padding>
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints /> 
                        <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="true" hgrow="ALWAYS" /> 
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <children>
                        <Text text="Family Name:"/>
                        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>
                    </children>
                </GridPane>
            </content>
        </ScrollPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```